# Pic24f microcontrller often restarts when placed in metal box

Tags: pic, metal

I have developed a vehicle tracking application , everything works fine nothing wrong in wrong condition. I want to check out the signal strength of the modem so i placed the modem in a  Metal box , a new problem has raised (i.e) My modem and micro controller  continuously getting restarted , i think some magnetic interference around the modem which makes my PIC micro controller and GPRS modem to get malfunctioning , is this is a reason for getting stopped or what else? Kindly suggest me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to properly ground the metal box.

The traces in your PCB can act as an receiver which induces current in them. If those traces have any connection with PIC it will cause trouble. You need to have a large ground plane to absorb the EM interference (if any) and connect it to the metal box.

Have a look at this post in Microchip Forum
[here](http://forum.microchip.com/tm.aspx?m=144105&mpage=1&key=&#144149)